# XSLT Copy all Nodes except 1 element

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<events>
    <main>
        <action>modification</action>
        <subAction>weights</subAction>
    </main>
</events>
<SeriesSet>
    <Series id="Price_0">
        <seriesBodies>
            <SeriesBody>
                <DataSeriesBodyType>Do Not Copy</DataSeriesBodyType>
            </SeriesBody>
        </SeriesBodies>
    </Series>
</SeriesSet>
```

How do i copy all xml and exclude the DataSeriesBodyType element

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to use the identity template (as you were using) and then use a template matching DataSeriesBodyType which does nothing.

The code would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When matching DataSeriesBodyType: do nothing -->
    <xsl:template match="DataSeriesBodyType" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to normalize the output to remove empty data text nodes, then add to the previous stylesheet the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have tried that but its returning the element without a value. i dont want the element to be displayed at all.

Comment: The XML that you posted is not the complete XML and it has some errors in it (e.g. seriesBody whith a closing tag SeriesBody) so I have checked my code with a corrected version of your XML (which maybe is not the same). Check that the name if the match="DataSeriesBodyType" matches exactly (upper case and lower case letters included) and if it is not working, post your complete XML.

Comment: And which element are you trying to exclude DataSeriesBodyType or SeriesBodyType? Just replace on the <xsl:template match="DataSeriesBodyType" /> the match attribute value with the  XML element name to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me as sometimes I need to create a tree without one element to make a variable and some times remove another to make another variable. Note that the main match should not match the root element "/" because if you do, it copies the whole three down only when processing just the one root element. But keep in-mind this solutions where we use apply-templates for all nodes will interfere with other templates you may have to do other jobs, so you would need to us the "mode" option to separate them.

```
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::DataSeriesBodyType)]|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not a very efficient solution. It would be better to leave the identity transform template *as is*, and add a template matching the parent element of the element you want to remove that does the above.

Comment: Can you show me, please.

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1be

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's great. Would posted yourself as that is your solution?