# XSL: replacing <br><br/> with another character

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an input xml document that I am transforming which has this content in an node:

```
 <misc-item>22 mm<br></br><fraction>7/8</fraction> in.</misc-item>
```

When I create a variable by selecting 'misc-item', the br and fraction tags disappear.  However, if I create a variable using 'misc-item/br' and test to see if it is finding the br, the test seems to work.

What I want to do is make the

```
 '<br></br>'
```

into a space or semicolon or something, but I have had no luck.  I tried getting the siblings of 'misc-item/br', but it has none.  I checked the child count of 'misc-item' and it is one.

Any help greatly appreciated.

I looked at the post identified as possible dupe.  I tried this to no avail:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode='PageOutput'>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="PageOutput" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br" mode='PageOutput'>
    <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
</xsl:template>
```

Since I am not ignoring an element as in the suggested dupe, but rather substituting, this doesn't seem to be quite right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT Copy all Nodes except 1 element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985139/xslt-copy-all-nodes-except-1-element)

Comment: In that dupe suggestion, change `<xsl:template match="DataSeriesBodyType" />` with `<xsl:template match="br">;</xsl:template>`. Is exactly same scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I create a variable by selecting 'misc-item', the br and fraction tags disappear. However, if I create a variable using 'misc-item/br' and test to see if it is finding the br, the test seems to work.

When you create a variable you're storing a reference to the `misc-item` node in the variable.  If you ask for the `value-of` that node you'll get just the text, with elements stripped out, but the variable still holds the node itself.

This is probably something you need to tackle using `apply-templates` instead of `value-of`.  A common theme is to have an "identity template" which essentially copies everything as-is but can be overridden with different behaviour for certain nodes by providing more specific templates.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace any br element with a semicolon -->
<xsl:template match="br">;</xsl:template>
```

You can use a *mode* to restrict these templates for use in specific situations only

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="strip-br">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="strip-br" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace any br element with a semicolon -->
<xsl:template match="br" mode="strip-br">;</xsl:template>
```

and now you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$miscitem/node()" mode="strip-br" />
```

instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$miscitem"/>` to get the result you're after.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the extra explanation!  Works perfectly